# Cryptographically-secure, exactly-weighted sampling

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

How do I choose `k` elements with replacement and weights under the following conditions?

- Randomness must be cryptographically-secure, e.g. as used in the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module.
- Weighting must be exact, i.e. use integral instead of floating-point arithmetic.

Self-authored code is likely to be less secure and efficient than available implementations.  To my best understanding, the following implementations don't meet my requirements.

- [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)
- [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

Comment: what's the point of the "Weighting must be exact" constraint?  note that "integer" might be a better term than integral which is easily confused with the maths operator

Comment: note that `random.SystemRandom.choices` seems to meet the first constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just rip apart the [choices implemention from the random module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/random.py#L477).  Something like:

```
from random import SystemRandom
from itertools import accumulate as _accumulate, repeat as _repeat
from bisect import bisect as _bisect

def choices(population, weights, *, k=1):
    randrange = SystemRandom().randrange
    n = len(population)
    cum_weights = list(_accumulate(weights))
    if len(cum_weights) != n:
        raise ValueError('The number of weights does not match the population')
    total = cum_weights[-1]
    if not isinstance(total, int):
        raise ValueError('Weights must be integer values')
    if total <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Total of weights must be greater than zero')
    bisect = _bisect
    hi = n - 1
    return [population[bisect(cum_weights, randrange(total), 0, hi)]
            for i in _repeat(None, k)]
```

which could be tested as:

```
from collections import Counter

draws = choices([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], k=1_000_000)
print(dict(sorted(Counter(draws).items())))
```

giving me:

```
{1: 166150, 2: 333614, 3: 500236}
```

which looks about right.

Update: just thought to check for off-by-one errors and it seems good here:

```
print(
    choices([1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 0], k=5),
    choices([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0], k=5),
    choices([1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1], k=5),
)
```

giving:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

which also seems right.

Comment: The bisect module was exactly what I needed.